# Define strange operators

Tags: soft-question

How can I render the *connected* sum of $n$ topological spaces (or other quite strange topological operations) in a "product-like" manner? What I'm looking for is writing, for example
$$
{\Large{*}}_{i=1}^n G_i
$$
for the free product of n groups. How can I render this with the # operation in topological spaces? (Yes, I'm studying Hatcher's AT...)

Comment: you'd probably get better answers if you ask over at tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: The Wikipedia article uses \bigvee.

Comment: I posted also in tex.stackexchange... Sorry for the bad question. Bigvee is already assigned to the wedge sum, very different from *connected* sum (I made a mistake in writing before)

Comment: Why not just do `$\#_{i=1}^n X_i$'?

Comment: P.S. $\#$ is an operation on manifolds, not arbitrary topological spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked over at tex.se, [Define strange operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5042/define-strange-operators), with an accepted answer by frabjous:

> The `\mathop{..}` command from amsmath makes its argument behave like a "large operator".

with some example code.